# How do I request a refresh token using OIDC

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, refresh-token

I am trying to implement refresh tokens with OIDC and OAuth2 and am having trouble understanding the workflow.  From what I do understand, using the Authorization Code flow, what gets the refresh token in the response from the `/token` endpoint is the presence of the `offline_access` scope in the `/authorize` request.

My question is how does the request to the token endpoint know that it should return a refresh token for that user logging in, if the `offline_access` scope is only sent to the `/authorize` endpoint or should that scope also be present in the token request?  Or is this a case where the refresh token should be generated and stored during the `/authorize` workflow, before the code is returned and then just looked up in the `/token` workflow to be returned there?

Specifically following this workflow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are sent during the Authorize request and from the Authorization Server's viewpoint the following actions are performed:

- code is returned to the caller
- code is cached with a short time to live (eg 1 minute)
- scopes are cached
- in some flows other details such as a PKCE verifier are also cached

Next the client makes an Authorization Code Grant request to exchange the code for tokens and the Authorization Server performs these actions:

- Looks up the code
- Applies PKCE verification checks
- Checks the redirect URI matches that of the original request
- Looks up cached scopes
- Looks up details from the OAuth client configuration, such as the refresh token lifetime
- Generates tokens based on the above data
- Deletes the cache entry, so that the same code cannot be processed again
- Returns tokens to the caller

It is useful as an application developer to have an understanding of the key points of the AS behaviour, as above, though I expect I'm missing an important point or two. My main focus tends to be integrating flows in my UIs and APIs.

Of course when it comes to the Authorization Server, we should always use a certified 3rd party implementation, such as a low cost cloud or free open source solution.